# Limiting number of integers before decimal point using .numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to limit input to a maximum of two integers before the decimal and a maximum of one after. (00.0 for example) I have been trying to make this work with the .numeric which can be found [here](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/numeric).

My call looks like this.

```
$(".setOneNumDec").numeric({
    negative: false,
    decimal: ".",
    scale: 3,
    decimalPlaces: 1
});
```

Currently the limit of one decimal place is working however the plugin is still allowing any number of integers before the decimal.

Comment: Looks like that plugin doesn't support the restriction you are looking for( a maximum bound). Maybe you could just take the value it gives you and check if it's `>=100' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you are using is let's say out of date. It's 2 years old (or didn't get any changes since) and these days any modern browser (even IE > 10) can handle the `number` type on input elements. So why use a plugin you don't need.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]');
element.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){

    var currentChar = parseInt(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode), 10);
    // the String.fromCharCode... is a special trick 
    // which is nicely explained here: 
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/25060122/2008111

    if(!isNaN(currentChar)) {
        var nextValue = this.value + currentChar;
        
        // check if next value is bigger then 100 the reset to 99.9
        if(parseInt(nextValue, 10) > 100) {
            return this.value = 99.9;
        }
        
        // decimal check here. if more then 2 decimal places remove the last one
        if((this.value.split('.')[1] || []).length > 1) {
          return this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0.1" max="99.9" step="0.1" />
```

Also when testing: Look how nice it's working even when using the arrows inside the input field.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you. And I can get rid of a library.

Comment: @joerdie you're welcome! Glad to hear and happy coding

Comment: @joerdie it has one bug though, just figured out now. You can type as many `0` as you want ... but I guess that's easy to fix and you can solve that